# My website not showing 404 error!

Tags: 404-error

My self-hosted website is no more showing 404 errors (of course for the pages that don't exist). I edited the 404 template of my theme and just updated the written text of the heading and body text, nothing else, and I get this now.

When I open a page that doesn't exist on my website, like (mywebsite).com/anythinguseless, the tab loads in a moment and shows just the link in the tab title. To be technical, it opens a webpage with nothing:

```
<html>

    <head></head>
    <body>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have some kind of syntax error in your 404 page or maybe in one of the other templates you have edited.

Comment: can be problem with htaccess or file permission error with ur hosting.